# If I moved the location of my generic "posts" page, do I need to change the slugs for all of the individual posts?

Tags: posts, urls, slug, breadcrumb

My company is restructuring our sitemap and one of the changes was moving the posts page.

**Original Slug:** .com/about/news-articles/

**New Slug:** .com/news-articles/

I did that in our staging environment and everything looks good as far as that redirect goes. However, all of the posts still have slugs in this format: **.com/about/news-articles/post-name/**

It also seems like this redirect is messing up my bread crumbs (see screen caps).

[image: News/articles breadcrumbs messed up]

[image: Duplicated breadcrumbs]

I've been searching for ways to edit the parent pages of posts, but I've had no luck there.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

I've got to figure this out before anything can be done in our production site.

Comment: Please give the code you are using to generate the breadcrumb.

Comment: @the_dramatist I don't have access to it. I only work on the front end stuff so all I can change is CSS and page content/slugs/etc.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid, with only CSS tweak it is not possible I think.

Comment: @the_dramatist Okay, what about just fixing the slugs of the posts themselves?

Comment: What is your permalink structure? Maybe check there for a start. How did you get "/about/..." in the URL in the first place?

Comment: @Pim News + Articles originally had the About page set as a parent. They have a custom field set up that allows you to choose a parent page if you want. I changed that field to "no parent" to make this structure change, which resulted in the issue above.